# GridView vs. Other layouts for memory game | Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a memory game. I've looked at the Android tutorials for GridView and, while it works, it is somewhat difficult to understand and customize. I would like to ask for advice and opinions on what layouts I should use for the memory game I'm working on. It'll be a simple "grid" of pictures and people will be trying to find the matching pairs.

Please provide what you think would be a good layout to use and the advantages/disadvantages of that layout. Layouts such as Gridview, LinearLayout, TableLayout, etc.

Are there any layouts that are simple and easy to customize for my memory game? I'm asking as someone who is new to programming. I have watched an introductory programming video lecture series from Stanford using Java, so I understand the basics of Java but I am not advanced.

More information, just in case you want to know:
I initially tried to create the GridView in java and not XML. But for some reason, the GridView wouldn't display on the emulator. It was just a blank screen. I believe it was because I did not have the layout set to MATCH_PARENT. But I don't know how to do that from java. I tried googling it, but I couldn't find an answer. I eventually settled on doing it through XML. If anyone knows how to do it through java, that would be very much appreciated.

I also had difficulty understanding the ImageAdapter class in the GridView tutorial: (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html). Specifically, I do not understand how or when the getView() function is called. It isn't explained in the tutorial.

I was able to get it to work but because I don't understand it very well, I am not sure how much I will be able to customize it for my memory game.

I'm sorry for the long post. My question is mainly about which layout I should use for my memory game. If you can answer the question about creating a GridView in java that displays on the emulator, that would be great.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I've tried using GridView but it has been difficult. I am unable to make it look pretty on both portrait and landscape modes. I don't know how to make it change depending on the display mode. Does anyone know? I'm going to try using TableLayout in XML and adding TableRows dynamically using Java. Here's a link to a tutorial I've found on how to do that: [Dynamic Rows Tutorial](http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Dynamically_adding_rows_to_TableLayout)

Comment: Using TableLayout in XML and adding TableRows and ImageViews dynamically using Java has been successful. I suppose it is because my understanding of Java and Android is not advanced enough for me to use GridView. Specifically, it is the ImageAdapter/BaseAdapter portion of GridView that I don't know how to customize. But I've been able to customize the dynamic TableRow and ImageView setup pretty well. It allows me greater flexibility in how I implement the game's layout.

Comment: Update: The "onClick" method (or whatever it's called) for ImageView doesn't have a parameter for its position in the layout. I had to go back and use GridView, after all. GridView's "onClick" method does pass a parameter for its position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a fairly straight-forward tutorial for extending `BaseAdapter` - which is exactly what you'll want to do.

Define your layout in XML. Use a GridView. Then just write a custom adapter to control what gets displayed in the grid.

http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=588

It's written with a ListView in mind but the same methods will be implemented for a GridView. If that is too advanced you'll need to start with a smaller app and build your understanding from a lower level.

Comment: Thanks, LeffelMania. Your link explained that getView() function for me. I guess it works automatically and behind the scenes? I think I understand the code that you wrote. The explanations you provided helped. I see that you recommended the GridView. If I want to customize the "layout" of the pictures for my memory game, would I modify the GridView or the MediaAdapter? Or do I modify both? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I've been experimenting with the GridView. I haven't been able to figure out how to customize the GridView so that it changes according to whether it is portrait or landscape. Do you think it's possible to use TableLayout in XML and dynamically add TableRows in java to make it prettier in both portrait and landscape modes? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Jack Smartie GridView is definitely the way to go. If it doesn't look right in one orientation you need to tweak your XML layout properties for the view. Setting the width and height to `wrap_content` and the layout_gravity to `center_horizontal` should help if you're not already doing so.